# Get Latest Data From Room with Paging 3 Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-paging

I want to show a list of items with pagination 3 and the data is from my local database with Room Library. I pre-populate my data to the Room Database with RoomDatabase.Callback provided by the room with JSON file. But the first time i open the app the list are not showing anything. I have to reopen my application and the items from the tables will shown.

Here are some snippets of the codes:

**quiz.json**

```json
[
    {
        "question": "Question 1",
        "type": "en",
        "answer": 0
    },
    {
        "question": "Question 2",
        "type": "en",
        "answer": 1
    }
]
```

**AppDatabase.kt**

```kotlin
@Database(
    entities = [QuizEntity::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun quizDao(): QuizDao

    private class AppDatabaseCallback(
        private val context: Context,
        private val scope: CoroutineScope
    ) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {

        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)
            INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                scope.launch {
                    val quizDao = database.quizDao()
                    quizDao.deleteAll()

                    fillQuizData(context, quizDao)
                }
            }
        }

      suspend fun fillQuizData(context: Context, quizDao: QuizDao) {
            val jsonArray = FileUtil.loadJsonArray(context, R.raw.quiz)
            try {
                jsonArray?.let {
                    for (i in 0 until it.length()) {
                        val item = it.getJSONObject(i)
                        val isAnswer = item.getInt("answer")
                        quizDao.insert(
                            QuizEntity(
                                0,
                                item.getString("question"),
                                item.getString("type"),
                                isAnswer == 1,
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            } catch (exception: JSONException) {
                exception.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(
            context: Context,
            scope: CoroutineScope
        ): AppDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "MyApplication.db"
                )
                    .addCallback(AppDatabaseCallback(context, scope))
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**QuizDao.kt**

```kotlin
@Dao
interface QuizDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE type=:type AND question LIKE '%' || :question || '%' LIMIT :size")
    suspend fun searchQuiz(type: String, size: Int, question: String = ""): List<QuizEntity>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(quizEntity: QuizEntity)

    @Query("DELETE FROM quiz")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

**QuizRepository.kt**

```kotlin
class QuizRepository @Inject constructor(private val quizDao: QuizDao) {

  fun getEnglishQuiz(query: String = ""): Flow < PagingData < QuizEntity >> {
    return Pager(PagingConfig(PAGE_SIZE)) {
      QuizPagingSource(quizDao, "en", query)
    }.flow
  }

  companion object {
    private
    const val PAGE_SIZE = 25
  }
}
```

**QuizViewModel.kt**

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class QuizViewModel @Inject constructor(private val quizRepository: QuizRepository) : ViewModel() {

    fun getEnglishQuizData(query: String = ""): Flow<PagingData<Quiz>> {
        return quizRepository.getEnglishQuiz(query).map {
            it.map { quiz ->
                Quiz(
                    quiz.id,
                    quiz.question,
                    quiz.type,
                    quiz.isAnswer
                )
            }
        }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```

**In My Activity:**

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch {
  binding.etSearch.getQueryTextChangeStateFlow()
    .debounce(500)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .flatMapLatest {
      query - >
        quizViewModel.getEnglishQuizData(query)
    }
    .collect {
      result - >
        quizAdapter.submitData(result)
    }
}
```

**Extensions for SearchView**

```kotlin
fun SearchView.getQueryTextChangeStateFlow(): StateFlow < String > {

  val query = MutableStateFlow("")

  setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String ? ): Boolean {
      return true
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
      query.value = newText
      return true
    }
  })

  return query

}
```

I have thought about adding one new function for my QuizDao which return LiveData of my QuizEntity and i observed it in my activity and check if the size is not the same i will call functions provided by paging 3 library which is either adapter.refreshed() or adapter.invalidated() if i'm not wrong. I haven't tried that so i don't know if that is works. Any solution?? Sorry for my bad english.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paging is notified of updates to DB via invalidation, which generates a new `PagingData` in the `Flow`. In your activity, make sure to use `.collectLatest` instead of `.collect`, so that you cancel the previous (empty) generation and use the new one once you receive it downstream.

e.g.,

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
  binding.etSearch.getQueryTextChangeStateFlow()
    ...
    .collectLatest {
      result - >
        quizAdapter.submitData(result)
    }
}
```

`.submitData` suspends until that generation is finished. Since Paging is powered by collector's scope, you shouldn't depend on it to eagerly cancel.